# Can I fetch "req.session" (express-session) data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch, express-session

```
app.get("/route1", async (req, res) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  console.log('TCL: req.session', req.session);
  res.send(req.session);
});

app.get("/route2", (req, res) => {
  req.session.test = "test";
  console.log('TCL: req.session', req.session);
  res.send(req.session);
});
```

route2 sets the session data, my terminal/browser logs it just fine.
If I visit route1 in the browser url bar the data successfully gets displayed both in the browser and terminal

If I try to fetch route2 in a react component I dont get the data I stored in req.session.test and my terminal logs only the cookie part of it like this:

```
TCL: req.session Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: false,
     secure: false } }
```

config:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: prodkeys.sessionSecret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false,
      }
}));
```

in component:

```
const isSession = await axios.get("http://localhost:5001/route1",
   {credentials: 'include', proxy: true});
```

Comment: Have you used Postman to see what happens if you call the API?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `withCredentials: true` instead of `credentials: 'include'`
I cannot find credentials option in official document.

Comment: yeah I tried this a couple of minutes before you commented together with installing cors, thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% which part fixed it, but I installed cors and configured my fetch this way and it solved it:

```
const isSession = await axios.get("http://localhost:5001/route1",
    {credentials: 'include', proxy: true, withCredentials: true});
```

Index.js:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['*'],
    methods: ['GET','POST'],
    credentials: true // enable set cookie
}));
```

Comment: I think it's due to proxy option. I guess it requires CORS to be enabled.